# Batch File - Command Output

Tags: batch-file

I'm redirecting the output of a command to a .txt file and I'm getting outputs such as

> "Command ran successfully"

How do I remove these messages?

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't solve your problem then edit your question and explain further:

```
command |find /v /i "Command ran successfully" >file.txt
```

Comment: Command >> file.txt : my command is returning "Command ran successfully" in the file file.txt. How can I prevent this?